# Help with database connection

Tags: database, configuration

While i am trying login to the application i am getting this error "Cannot open database requested in login 'HealthCare'. Login fails. Login failed for user 'HOME-7A082AE66C\Sumit'."  Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //string uid = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
        //string Password = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
        con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=;password=;Database=HealthCare;trusted_Connection=true");
        switch(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:                                       
                cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from login where Userid=@Uid and Password=@Password",con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Uid",SqlDbType.VarChar,10));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password",SqlDbType.VarChar,20));
                cmd.Parameters["@Uid"].Value=TextBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value=TextBox2.Text;
                con.Open();
                dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/registration.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/errormessage.aspx");
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
                break;
            case 1:                    
                cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from login where Userid=@Uid and Password=@Password",con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Uid",SqlDbType.VarChar,10));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password",SqlDbType.VarChar,20));
                cmd.Parameters["@Uid"].Value=TextBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value=TextBox2.Text;
                con.Open();
                dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/doctordatabase.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/errormessage.aspx");                    
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
                break;
            case 2:                    
                cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from login where Userid=@Uid and Password=@Password",con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Uid",SqlDbType.VarChar,10));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password",SqlDbType.VarChar,20));
                cmd.Parameters["@Uid"].Value=TextBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value=TextBox2.Text;
                con.Open();
                dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(dr.Read())
                {

                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/diagnosis.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/eHealthCare/http://localhost/eHealthCare/errormessage.aspx");
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        con.Close();     

    }
```

Comment: Could you try reformatting your code it's a bit hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Is your database SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have login access? and is the password correct?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that sql server excepts connections over tcp/ip by trying to log in on to the server  using sql server management studio using tcp/ip (Connection Properties--> Network protocoll) if that doesn't work then open up the TCP/IP for this instance.

Comment: In that case the connection would fail altogether. The error message says that the login failed, so it's some kind of security issue.